# How to specify Scope for SubComponent when using @ContributesAndroidInjector

Tags: android, dagger-2, dagger

I'm trying to understand the new New Android Injector with Dagger 2 from [from this blog post](https://medium.com/@iammert/new-android-injector-with-dagger-2-part-1-8baa60152abe). I understood the concept of [@ContributesAndroidInjector](https://medium.com/@iammert/new-android-injector-with-dagger-2-part-2-4af05fd783d0#c38d), and how it avoids repetition of code as described in the blog

***[UI subcomponents(MainActivityComponent and DetailActivityComponent) are just like bridge in the graph. We don’t even have to use our brain to create this class](https://medium.com/@iammert/new-android-injector-with-dagger-2-part-2-4af05fd783d0#3e87)***.

So, if you want your subcomponents to be in a different scope (say @PerActivity), how would we achieve this, since we are not creating the sub-component at all?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this:

```
@PerActivity
@ContributesAndroidInjector
abstract YourActivity yourActivity();
```

which will generate something like this:

```
@Subcomponent
@PerActivity
public interface YourActivitySubcomponent extends AndroidInjector<YourActivity> {
    @Subcomponent.Builder
    abstract class Builder extends AndroidInjector.Builder<YourActivity> {}
}
```

Comment: Okay, so this is as good as creating a SubComponent for `YourActivity` and putting a Scope to it?

Comment: @Jrd yes, see my updated answer with the code that Dagger will generate for you